# count entrys, excluding double in different column

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am searching for a mysql query that provides me the steamids of users that connected to the most servers, but exclude servers the steamid were already on.

Not sure how to describe properly as i am not a native english speaker.

```
id  | steamid  | onserveradress
--- | -------- | --------------
1   | steam:11 | 111.111.11.111
2   | steam:11 | 222.222.22.222
3   | steam:22 | 333.333.33.333
4   | steam:11 | 111.111.11.111
5   | steam:33 | 111.111.11.111
6   | steam:44 | 444.444.44.444
7   | steam:44 | 222.222.22.222
8   | steam:11 | 444.444.44.444
```

so i would like the outcome to be

```
steamid  | count
-------- | -----
steam:11 | 3
steam:44 | 2
steam:22 | 1
steam:33 | 1
```

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT onserveraddress) GROUP BY streamid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're after this...

```
SELECT steamid
     , COUNT(DISTINCT onserveradress) total 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP  
    BY steamid 
 ORDER 
    BY total;
```